# how to submit kaggle competition submission file ? . Please disable internet in the Notebook editor and save a new version

Tags: kaggle

while after running kernel and after preparing the the submission file when i click the submit button it show warning like this

Cannot submit 
Submission files must be named "submission.csv" for this Competition.

[image: Your Notebook cannot use internet access in this competition. Please disable internet in the Notebook editor and save a new version.]

Answer (score 1):

In some kernel competitions, access to internet ressources are not allowed. You need to disable internet access (there's a slider to do so when you edit the notebook) before commiting again your notebook.